# Should we rename variables, database tables, etc when program name changed?

Tags: rename, naming-conventions, naming

Let say a company has an internal program called  *Service Checklist*.

Because the program named *Service Checklist*, **the programmer creates a name on variables, pages, database tables, stored procedures and anything else based on the program name**.

For example :

- Variable named `ListServiceChecklist` or `ListSC`
- A page named`CreateServiceChecklist` or `CreateSC`
- Stored Procedure named `GetServiceChecklist` or `GetSC`
- Table named `ServiceChecklist`

This program has been used for years, and new small improvements added every year.

---

Then someday the manager decided to **rename the program** from *Service Checklist* to *E-Checklist*, and he needs it to be done fast. So if a text that is shown to the user contain words *Service Checklist*, it must be changed to *E-Checklist*

For example :

- Text Menu `List Service Checklist` must be changed to `List E-Checklist`
- Alert message `Success create Service Checklist` changed to `Success create E-Checklist`

So the programmer started to change all the text from *Service Checklist* to *E-Checklist* on the front end side. **But what about all the variables, pages name, database tables, stored procedures, etc?**

- If the programmer leaves it, other programmers will be confused as the name doesn't make any sense anymore.
- If the programmer renames all the variables, etc, it will take a lot of time and a huge pain in the ass.

As a programmer what's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Like most things in programming, it depends. There isn't a one rule fits all. 
Ideally everything gets changed to help code readability but in many cases the amount of time this would take doesn't justify the benefits.

You have to take into consideration the amount of time it will take to do these updates and measure it against how much time it will save you in the future.

It also depends on the size of the project, how many times the code gets updates, how much time the team has to work on this type of things and probably a few others I can't think of right now.